# The type or namespace name `UnityEditor' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Pls help me correct this problem.

Assets/Menu.cs(97,73): warning CS0618: `UnityEditor.EditorUtility.GetAssetPath(UnityEngine.Object)' is obsolete:`Use AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath'

Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors

Assets/Menu.cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `UnityEditor' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.Linq;

struct ObjMaterial
{
    public string name;
    public string textureName;
}

public class Menu : MonoBehaviour { 

    public int window; 

    void Start () { 
        window = 1;

    } 

    private static int vertexOffset = 0;
    private static int normalOffset = 0;
    private static int uvOffset = 0;


    //User should probably be able to change this. It is currently left as an excercise for
    //the reader.
    private static string targetFolder = "ExportedObj";


    private static string MeshToString(Component mf, Dictionary<string, ObjMaterial> materialList) 
    {



        Mesh m;
        Material[] mats;

        if(mf is MeshFilter)
        {
            m = (mf as MeshFilter).mesh;
            mats = mf.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterials;
        }
        else if(mf is SkinnedMeshRenderer)
        {
            m = (mf as SkinnedMeshRenderer).sharedMesh;
            mats = (mf as SkinnedMeshRenderer).sharedMaterials;
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append("g ").Append(mf.name).Append("\n");
        foreach(Vector3 lv in m.vertices) 
        {
            Vector3 wv = mf.transform.TransformPoint(lv);

            //This is sort of ugly - inverting x-component since we're in
            //a different coordinate system than "everyone" is "used to".
            sb.Append(string.Format("v {0} {1} {2}\n",-wv.x,wv.y,wv.z));
        }
        sb.Append("\n");

        foreach(Vector3 lv in m.normals) 
        {
            Vector3 wv = mf.transform.TransformDirection(lv);

            sb.Append(string.Format("vn {0} {1} {2}\n",-wv.x,wv.y,wv.z));
        }
        sb.Append("\n");

        foreach(Vector3 v in m.uv) 
        {
            sb.Append(string.Format("vt {0} {1}\n",v.x,v.y));
        }

        for (int material=0; material < m.subMeshCount; material ++) {
            sb.Append("\n");
            sb.Append("usemtl ").Append(mats[material].name).Append("\n");
            sb.Append("usemap ").Append(mats[material].name).Append("\n");

            //See if this material is already in the materiallist.
            try
            {
                ObjMaterial objMaterial = new ObjMaterial();

                objMaterial.name = mats[material].name;


                objMaterial.textureName = EditorUtility.GetAssetPath(mats[material].mainTexture);
                //else 
                    //objMaterial.textureName = null;

                materialList.Add(objMaterial.name, objMaterial);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                //Already in the dictionary
            }


            int[] triangles = m.GetTriangles(material);
            for (int i=0;i<triangles.Length;i+=3) 
            {
                //Because we inverted the x-component, we also needed to alter the triangle winding.
                sb.Append(string.Format("f {1}/{1}/{1} {0}/{0}/{0} {2}/{2}/{2}\n", 
                    triangles[i]+1 + vertexOffset, triangles[i+1]+1 + normalOffset, triangles[i+2]+1 + uvOffset));
            }
        }

        vertexOffset += m.vertices.Length;
        normalOffset += m.normals.Length;
        uvOffset += m.uv.Length;

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private static void Clear()
    {
        vertexOffset = 0;
        normalOffset = 0;
        uvOffset = 0;
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, ObjMaterial> PrepareFileWrite()
    {
        Clear();

        return new Dictionary<string, ObjMaterial>();
    }

    private static void MaterialsToFile(Dictionary<string, ObjMaterial> materialList, string folder, string filename)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(folder + "/" + filename + ".mtl")) 
        {
            foreach( KeyValuePair<string, ObjMaterial> kvp in materialList )
            {
                sw.Write("\n");
                sw.Write("newmtl {0}\n", kvp.Key);
                sw.Write("Ka  0.6 0.6 0.6\n");
                sw.Write("Kd  0.6 0.6 0.6\n");
                sw.Write("Ks  0.9 0.9 0.9\n");
                sw.Write("d  1.0\n");
                sw.Write("Ns  0.0\n");
                sw.Write("illum 2\n");

                if (kvp.Value.textureName != null)
                {
                    string destinationFile = kvp.Value.textureName;


                    int stripIndex = destinationFile.LastIndexOf('/');//FIXME: Should be Path.PathSeparator;

                    if (stripIndex >= 0)
                        destinationFile = destinationFile.Substring(stripIndex + 1).Trim();


                    string relativeFile = destinationFile;

                    destinationFile = folder + "/" + destinationFile;

                    Debug.Log("Copying texture from " + kvp.Value.textureName + " to " + destinationFile);

                    try
                    {
                        //Copy the source file
                        File.Copy(kvp.Value.textureName, destinationFile);
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }   


                    sw.Write("map_Kd {0}", relativeFile);
                }

                sw.Write("\n\n\n");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void MeshToFile(Component mf, string folder, string filename) 
    {
        Dictionary<string, ObjMaterial> materialList = PrepareFileWrite();

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(folder +"/" + filename + ".obj")) 
        {
            sw.Write("mtllib ./" + filename + ".mtl\n");

            sw.Write(MeshToString(mf, materialList));
        }

        MaterialsToFile(materialList, folder, filename);
    }

    private static void MeshesToFile(Component[] mf, string folder, string filename) 
    {
        Dictionary<string, ObjMaterial> materialList = PrepareFileWrite();

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(folder +"/" + filename + ".obj")) 
        {
            sw.Write("mtllib ./" + filename + ".mtl\n");

            for (int i = 0; i < mf.Length; i++)
            {
                sw.Write(MeshToString(mf[i], materialList));
            }
        }

        MaterialsToFile(materialList, folder, filename);
    }

    private static bool CreateTargetFolder()
    {
        try
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetFolder);
        }
        catch
        {
            //EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Error!", "Failed to create target folder!", "");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }



    void OnGUI () { 
        GUI.BeginGroup (new Rect (Screen.width / 2 - 100, Screen.height / 2 - 100, 200, 200)); 
        if(window == 1) 
        { 
            if(GUI.Button (new Rect (10,30,180,30), "Экспортировать")) 
            { 

                if (!CreateTargetFolder())
                    return;

                //GameObject[] gos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Boat");
                //Selection.objects = gos;

                GameObject[] selection = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Boat");
                //Transform[] selection = Selection.GetTransforms(SelectionMode.Editable | SelectionMode.ExcludePrefab);

                if (selection.Length == 0)
                {
                    //EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("No source object selected!", "Please select one or more target objects", "");
                    return;
                }

                int exportedObjects = 0;

                ArrayList mfList = new ArrayList();

                for (int i = 0; i < selection.Length; i++)
                {
                    Component[] meshfilter = selection[i].GetComponentsInChildren(typeof(MeshFilter)).Concat(selection[i].GetComponentsInChildren(typeof(SkinnedMeshRenderer))).ToArray();

                    for (int m = 0; m < meshfilter.Length; m++)
                    {
                        exportedObjects++;
                        mfList.Add(meshfilter[m]);
                    }
                }

                if (exportedObjects > 0) 
                {
                    Component[] mf = new Component[mfList.Count];

                    for (int i = 0; i < mfList.Count; i++) {
                        mf [i] = (Component)mfList [i];
                    }

                    string filename = /*EditorApplication.currentScene +*/ "_" + exportedObjects;

                    int stripIndex = filename.LastIndexOf ('/');//FIXME: Should be Path.PathSeparator

                    if (stripIndex >= 0)
                        filename = filename.Substring (stripIndex + 1).Trim ();

                    MeshesToFile (mf, targetFolder, filename);

                }

            } 

            if(GUI.Button (new Rect (10,150,180,30), "Выход")) 
            { 
                window = 5; 
            } 
        } 

        if(window == 5) 
        { 
            GUI.Label(new Rect(50, 10, 180, 30), "Вы уже выходите?");   
            if(GUI.Button (new Rect (10,40,180,30), "Да")) 
            { 
                Application.Quit(); 
            } 
            if(GUI.Button (new Rect (10,80,180,30), "Нет")) 
            { 
                window = 1; 
            } 
        } 
        GUI.EndGroup (); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: It seems very odd that you're getting a warning specific to a class in the namespace *and* an error that it can't find the namespace. But given the warning, is there any reason you're not just using `AssetDatabase` instead?

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/576746/build-error-the-type-or-namespace-name-unityeditor.html

Comment: But what function can I use instead of EditorUtility.GetAssetPath?

Comment: @RayRove AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath, perhaps?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Before using any Unity API, it is very important to check the API namespace. If the namespace is from `UnityEditor` then it is only meant to work in the Editor only. This is used to make an Editor plugin. You can't use it in a build and it will throw an error when building for any platform.

According the docs, [`AssetDatabase`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.html) and [`EditorUtility`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.html) class are from the `UnityEditor` namespace.

[image]

You have to re-design your game to work without the `GetAssetPath` function. You can definitely make a game without that function. I can't tell what you are doing but you should look into the [`Resources`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html) class. This will help you load your GameObjects during run-time.

To solve your current problem,

Replace

```
using UnityEditor;
```

with

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif
```

Then replace

```
objMaterial.textureName = EditorUtility.GetAssetPath(mats[material].mainTexture);
```

with

```
        objMaterial.textureName = "";
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        objMaterial.textureName = EditorUtility.GetAssetPath(mats[material].mainTexture);
#endif
```

You can also put your `Menu` script in a folder in the `Assets`/`Editor` directory but please understand that this does not solve the problem that your code won't work in a build. It will only allow your project to build without those errors in your question. The classes from the `UnityEditor` namespace are only used for Editor plugin.

Comment: I using Resources, but it don

Answer (score 7):

This happens because classes that are using UnityEditor need to be put under a folder called Editor: Assets/Editor
If you do that, the problem will be gone

Comment: This fixed my issue when I was trying to write a class that implemented `UnityEditor.Build.IPostprocessBuildWithReport` (which is strictly for performing tweaks after compiling a Unity application, and doesn't get included in the output build itself).

Comment: What the actual f**? Why is that? Nevertheless thank you for your answer, it saves me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Assembly definitions (dlls) this can also happen. No dll that includes editor stuff will be included in the build. Best to make a separate dll for editor stuff.

[image: Picture of assembly definition settings]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the offending line had been added accidentally, maybe by misclicking some setting at some point.

Since none of my code actually needed the UnityEditor, the solution was to:

1. View the full error message in the console to find the .cs file that was causing the error:

```
using UnityEditor.Experimental.GraphView;
```

2. Delete or comment out the line.
3. Repeat the above steps where needed.
4. Build and run the project to confirm that everything works.