# How do I get a Unity scene name when they are stored as an array of Objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene

I have a list of Objects. They are Unity scenes.

```
public Object[] scenes;
```

I would like to fill this array with unity scenes, as a convenient way of storing the sequential order they should load within Unity's inspector.

I attempted to use the SceneManager to load a level using a reference to this array

```
public int currentSceneNumber = 0;
public void LoadNext()
{
    if (scenes.Length >= currentSceneNumber + 1)
    {
        currentSceneNumber += 1;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(scenes[currentSceneNumber].ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Level.cs: Unable to load next level.");
        return;
    }
}
```

But turning the scene into a string results in 'scenename(UnityEngine.SceneAsset)' The (login (UnityEngine.SceneAsset) is the problem part. It will result in the following error

```
Scene 'prototype02_Scene (UnityEngine.SceneAsset)' couldn't be loaded because it has not been added to the build settings or the AssetBundle has not been loaded.
To add a scene to the build settings use the menu File->Build Settings...
```

How do I get the scene name as a string from the scene object in my array?

Comment: He said clearly, add all scenes to `Build Settings` and then check again your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **can't** do this outside the Editor.

When you use `public UnityEngine.Object[] scenes;` to hold the Scenes, Unity will use [`SceneAsset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneAsset.html) as the placeholder to hold those scenes.

The problem with this is that `SceneAsset` is from the `UnityEditor` namespace which means that your code *will only work in the Editor* with the the [AssetDatabase](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.html). You can't build it to run on any standalone platform. You will get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064746/the-type-or-namespace-name-unityeditor-could-not-be-found) error if you attempt to build your project.

This is how to get all the scenes and store them in an array(Should work in the Editor and build):

```
public Scene[] scenes;

...


void initScenes()
{   
    int sceneCount = SceneManager.sceneCountInBuildSettings;
    scenes = new Scene[sceneCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < sceneCount; i++)
    {
        scenes[i] = SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex(sceneCount);
    }
}
```

Your loading code:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(scenes[currentSceneNumber].name);
```

---

If you are sure that this is an Editor plugin and not something you need to build or run outside the Editor then here is your answer:

First of all, you are using the Object name which has nothing to do with the scene name since `Object.ToString()` is an override function that retrieves the 
name of the Object.

Just cast the Object array to `SceneAsset` then access the name of the scene from that instead of the name of the `Object` like you are currently doing.

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(((SceneAsset)scenes[currentSceneNumber]).name);
```

or

```
SceneAsset scene = scenes[currentSceneNumber] as SceneAsset;
SceneManager.LoadScene(scene.name);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer programmer. It all makes sense. You're proposed solution I can imagine works but unfortunately defeats the purpose of what I'm attempting.

I'd like to avoid having to use the build settings window to organise my scenes.

I want to have the convenience of dragging and dropping into the inspector window a select amount of scenes that are relevant to the game build.

Comment: To avoid using the Build Settings, you have to write more code. You have to write your own custom Editor build script (**ScriptA**)  with Menu that you can use to build your project. You can then write another script(**ScriptB**) that takes your SceneAsset in the array add them into Assetbundle then copies the AssetBundle  to the StreamingAssets folder. When you click your build function from **ScriptA**, it will preform actions I described in **ScriptB** then it will return back to **ScriptA** and build the project.