# I've got error CS0234 when I tried to build my 2D project in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'am new in Unity, so don't be angry)

I tried to build my game, but I've got those errors:

-Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(5,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'WSA' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

-Assets\Scripts\SpawnMovePoint.cs(4,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Build' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

-Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor.Build.Reporting; // Problem Line
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class SpawnMovePoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform left, right, _point;
    float MinX, MaxX;
 


    public void Start()
    {
        MinX = left.position.x;
        MaxX = right.position.x;
    }



    public void CreatePoint()
    {
        _point.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(MinX, 
  MaxX),_point.position.y,_point.position.z);
    }
}
```

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine.WSA;//Problem Line


public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
```

What should I do to fix them?
How can I make these references?
What does it mean, what 'Build' does not exist in 'UnityEditor'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The type or namespace name \`UnityEditor' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064746/the-type-or-namespace-name-unityeditor-could-not-be-found)

Answer (score 0):

'-Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors'
This simply means that the script cannot be compiled because it contains some errors, pretty straight forward.

Can you tell me why do you need 'UnityEditor.Build.Reporting and WSA ??
Also, you should share more code so we can see where and why you are using a certain namespace and whether the code will work without them or not.

Answer (score 0):

Please Include more information to help me as well as others to understand and help fix your problem. Make sure to also show any research you have done to try and fix this problem.