# UNITY error CS0246: The type or namespace name `MenuItem' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

For some reason i keep getting a referencing error for:

(8,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `MenuItem' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

(24,26): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `SerializedObject' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;


public class AudioSourceReplacement { 

    [MenuItem("FMOD Tools/Replace Audio Emitters")]
    private static void ReplaceEmitters()
    {
        AudioSource[] audioSources = Object.FindObjectsOfType<AudioSource>();

        foreach (AudioSource audioSource in audioSources)
        {
            if (audioSource.clip == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            string eventName = audioSource.clip.name;
            string eventPath = (audioSource.spatialBlend < 0.5f ? "event:/Ambience/2D/" : "event:/Ambience/3D/") + eventName;

            FMODUnity.StudioEventEmitter emitter = audioSource.gameObject.AddComponent<FMODUnity.StudioEventEmitter>();
            emitter.Event = eventPath;
            var so = new SerializedObject(emitter);
            so.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }

        for (int i=0;i<audioSources.Length;i++)
        {
            GameObject.DestroyImmediate(audioSources[i]);
        }
    }

    [MenuItem("FMOD Tools/Force All Emitters Play On Start")]
    private static void EmittersPlayOnStart()
    {
        FMODUnity.StudioEventEmitter[] audioSources = Object.FindObjectsOfType<FMODUnity.StudioEventEmitter>();

        foreach (FMODUnity.StudioEventEmitter audioSource in audioSources)
        {
            audioSource.PlayEvent = FMODUnity.EmitterGameEvent.ObjectStart;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The type or namespace name \`UnityEditor' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064746/the-type-or-namespace-name-unityeditor-could-not-be-found)

Answer (score 6):

I faced with build-compile errors where editor-assembly (.asmdef in Editor folder) was setup incorrectly.
In case if you have editor-assembly check `Editor` checkbox in `Platforms` section.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details how to get to this menu?

Comment: @Tina P This is Inspector view of [.asmdef file](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html). Select in _Project_ section file with ext. _.asmdef_.

Comment: This solved my issue.  While it might be obvious from the image included, I totally missed that the top "Any Platforms" was unchecked.  So with `Any Platforms` unchecked you would **only include** the Editor platform, with it checked you would then need to **exclude all except the editor** platform.  Obviously going with the above approach would be ideal.

Answer (score 3):

You have to put your script inside your "Editor" folder. "Assets/Editor/AudioSourceReplacement.cs" should do the trick.

Comment: I added it to the editor file and it still says the same errors when compiling

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, you can have the editor scripts in any folder you'd like but if you want to put them in any other than "Assets/Editor", you'll have to create an Assembly Definition for that folder and mark it as Editor platform

Comment: Idk I have a couple editor scripts (located in Assets/Editor) whose namespace refused to be found by any scripts outside of the Editor folder. Luckily creating an assembly definition finally resolved the frustrating issue but I still don't understand why it was happening in the first place, given everything was in the proper location.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen because you didn't put this script inside an 'Editor' folder. It's one of these [Special Folders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html).

Comment: I added it to the editor file and it still says the same errors.

Comment: just to clarify, you need to add it to an Editor **folder** for it to work. Do you perhaps have any asmdef files in the folder-tree?